# In data factory does Azure Event trigger wait till full file is copied?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

Let us say that I am copying a 10 GB file to an ADLS location and this location is being monitored by an Azure Event trigger. Will the Event trigger wait for the full 10 GB file to be copied to trigger the event OR trigger the pipeline as soon as file starts copying?. If the pipeline gets kicked off as soon as the file starts to copy how can we delay it so that the pipeline can wait till the full file is copied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, the ADF is triggered once the entire file is uploaded based on event trigger.

[image]

ADF trigger :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger
Once the file is created (is fully uploaded) then the trigger fires.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:
It depends which API was used to copy the file.
If it's **Blob REST APIs**

"In that case, the Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated event is triggered when the CopyBlob operation is initiated and not when the Block Blob is completely committed."
If it's **Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 REST APIs**

"when clients use the CreateFile and FlushWithClose operations that are available in the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST API."